Function with Typescript and Prisma doesn't get loaded in Azure
I have a Yoga-GraphQL API server application written in typescript using VS Code.

node version : 22.8.0
npm version : 10.8.2
Azure Function version 4.x

My application uses Prisma client for database model.
When I run my application locally it works perfectly fine.
When I deploy the code to Azure Function (tried Consumption plan or Flex Consumption) it is not loading the function.
What I have tried

I checked the main entry point , the folder structure and the likes.
Everything is proper
I use my simple hello world schema it works fine

On my analysis I have found that if the function code calls the database
it is giving an error. I have confirmed this by hardcoding the database variables.
A part of my package.json is given below.
I have tried troubleshooting from Azure Function portal and Application Insights. I haven't got any clue that works.
I feel I'm missing to fire prisma generate while deploying to Azure via VS Code.
Any help on this is greatly appreciated.
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/package",
  "name": "api-gateway",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "GraphQL API Gateway",
  "main": "dist/src/functions/*.js",
  "scripts": {
      "build": "npm run compile && npm run prisma:generate",
      "check:all": "concurrently npm:check:pretty npm:check:lint npm:check:type",
      "check:lint": "eslint .",
      "check:pretty": "prettier --check .",
      "check:type": "tsc --noEmit",
      "clean": "rimraf dist",
      "compile": "tsc",
      "dev": "NODE_ENV=development tsx watch --clear-screen=false src/main.ts",
      "doc:graphql:generate": "magidoc generate",
      "doc:graphql:preview": "magidoc preview --port 4100",
      "lint-staged": "lint-staged",
      "local": "tsx src/main.ts",
      "prepare": "husky",
      "prisma:db:pull": "prisma db pull",
      "prisma:db:seed": "prisma db seed",
      "prisma:generate": "prisma generate",
      "prisma:migrate:dev": "prisma migrate dev --name",
      "prestart": "npm run clean && npm run build",
      "start": "func start",
      "start-v": "npm run clean && npm run build && func start --verbose",
      "pretest": "npm run check:all && npm run build",
      "test": "echo \"Tests are not implemented yet\"",
      "tscc": "tsc --showConfig",
      "watch": "tsc -w",
      "postinstall": "prisma generate" 
  },

Update
In Flex Consumption Plan (Linux) I am able to see the function loaded but it shows error as below

Update 2
Code as reply
This is my schema.prisma
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["multiSchema"]
}

generator pothos {
  provider = "prisma-pothos-types"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
  schemas  = ["product", "matr"]
}

model Address {
  id              Int               @id @default(autoincrement())
  addressLine1    String            @db.Text
  ...

  @@schema("product")
}

model Contact {
  id                     Int               @id @default(autoincrement())
  contactId           String?
  accountId           String?
...
  @@schema("product")
}

Below is my structure of Function App (Ver 4) showing the code in index.ts

index.ts is inside schema folder - seen in the screenshot.
There is no index.ts under src.
But with this structure it works fine in local.
it also works fine in local and Azure as well by
(i) removing all import .ts inside the index.ts file that relates to a value\call to DB
or
(ii)hard coding values related to DB in those files;
with the same code structure.


My http trigger function code is
    import { createYoga } from 'graphql-yoga'
import { InvocationContext, HttpRequest, HttpResponseInit, app } from '@azure/functions'
import { schema } from '../schema'

/**
 * Create the Graphql-Yoga server
 */
const yoga = createYoga({
  graphqlEndpoint: '/graphql',
  schema: schema,
  graphiql: true,
})

/**
 * Create the handler for Azure function
 *
 * @param req The request object
 * @param context The context object
 *
 * @returns The response object
 */
const httpTrigger1 = async function (
  req: HttpRequest,
  context: InvocationContext,
): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
  //  Invoke the Graphql server
  const response = await yoga.fetch(req.url, {
    method: req.method?.toString(),
    body: req.body,
    headers: req.headers as HeadersInit,
  })

  const responseHeaders = Object.fromEntries(response.headers.entries())

  // Log the response details
  context.log('Response Headers:', responseHeaders)

  const responseText = await response.text()

  //  Prepare the response object and send back
  return {
    status: response.status,
    body: responseText,
    headers: responseHeaders,
  }
}

/**
 * Set the configuration for the Azure function
 */
app.http('graphql', {
  methods: ['POST', 'GET'],
  authLevel: 'anonymous',
  handler: httpTrigger1,
})

export { httpTrigger1 }


Please share your function code. @jAntoni

I have followed this document to use Prisma in Azure typescript V4 function and I did following steps to achieve it.

Executed npm install @prisma @prisma/client and then npx prisma init in the terminal which created .env and the schema.prisma file.
Provided the correct connection string of postgres database in .env file.
Then executed npx prisma generate command which created Prisma client libraries in a separate folder named Prisma. I am using all the default code here.
I have the given folder structure and below codes in the mentioned files.

|   .env
|   .funcignore
|   .gitignore
|   host.json
|   local.settings.json
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
|   tsconfig.json
|
+---.vscode
|       extensions.json
|       launch.json
|       settings.json
|       tasks.json
|
+---dist
|   \---src
|       |   index.js
|       |   index.js.map
|       |
|       \---functions
|               httpTrigger1.js
|               httpTrigger1.js.map
|
+---node_modules
|
+---prisma
|   |   schema.prisma
|   |
|   \---client
|       |   default.d.ts
|       |   default.js
|       |   edge.d.ts
|       |   edge.js
|       |   index-browser.js
|       |   index.d.ts
|       |   index.js
|       |   package.json
|       |   query_engine-windows.dll.node
|       |   schema.prisma
|       |   wasm.d.ts
|       |   wasm.js
|       |
|       \---runtime
|               edge-esm.js
|               edge.js
|               index-browser.d.ts
|               index-browser.js
|               library.d.ts
|               library.js
|               react-native.js
|               wasm.js
|
\---src
    |   index.ts
    |
    \---functions
            httpTrigger1.ts

httpTrigger1.ts -
import { app, HttpRequest, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext } from "@azure/functions";
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';  

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

interface TodoRequestBody {
    todo: string;
}

export async function httpTrigger1(request: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
    context.log(`HTTP function processed request for URL "${request.url}"`);

    try {
        const body = await request.json() as TodoRequestBody;
        
        if (body && body.todo) {
            const todo = body.todo;
            const item = await prisma.todo.create({
                data: { todo }
            });

            return {
                status: 200,
                jsonBody: item
            };
        } else {
            return {
                status: 400,
                body: "Please pass a todo in the request body"
            };
        }
    } catch (error) {
        context.log(error);

        return {
            status: 500,
            body: "An error occurred on the server"
        };
    }
}

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: httpTrigger1
});

schema.prisma -
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model todo {
  completed Boolean? @default(false)
  id        Int      @default(autoincrement()) @id
  todo      String
}

package.json-
{
  "name": "79045076",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "prestart": "npm run clean && npm run build",
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^4.0.0",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.x",
    "prisma": "^5.20.0",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "main": "dist/src/{index.js,functions/*.js}"
}


I have added DATABASE_URL in App settings of function app.



I have used both npx func azure functionapp publish {functionAppName} command  and the deploy to Azure Function option present in the Workspace of vs code in order to deploy this function to a Linux Consumption plan Function App. Make sure you are getting the trigger endpoint post successful deployment.


I am able to create a record in the database successfully.


Thank you very much for this info . I'll be checking this. I have also updated the Question with additional info you have asked for. Please check if the structure, the way of calling the entities within index ... are fine. Trying a resolution for this for so many days now. Any thing to resolve here with your steps will really be great.

Also that I don't see under prisma the folders
client
|       |   default.d.ts
|       |   default.js
|       |   edge.d.ts and runtime ......, would that be the reason?

@jAntoni Yes, those files should be present under prisma folder. Have you followed the given steps in my answer?

I tried a very basic Hello World program with FunctionApp (NO graphQL or any other libraries added). Its working fine locally and in Azure. I then added import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'; -It still works Next I added the line const prisma = new PrismaClient(); With this it worked locally but gives an error when deployed to Azure Error: Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime. I'm sharing my finding here, thinking this could reveal the cause of problem and can help to get a solution for the issue.
